# How to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} | \frac{2}{z-n^2/z} | $ converges?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am wondering how to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} | \frac{2}{z-n^2/z} | $ converges. Wolframalpha says it does, by a comparison test. But with which series should we compare this series to prove it is convergent? I was thinking about $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} $, but I am not sure how obtain the required inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ | \frac{2}{z-n^2/z} | =\frac{2|z|}{|z^2-n^2|}\sim_\infty \frac{2|z|}{n^2}$$
and the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent so the given series is absolutely convergent by comparaison.